# Kafka JDBC Source Connector limitations

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

In the documentation for Kafka JDBC Source Connector: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/overview.html there is this note that when using the timestamp column mode:

*The connector might not be able to fetch some records from a table in this mode. For example, if you set batch.max.rows to 10 and have more than 10 records with the same timestamp in a table, the additional records (with the same timestamp) will be ignored*

I'm analyzing the connector for a certain use case and wanted to see exactly how this limitation works but I could not reproduce it. What I've tried:

- create a DB with a single table having and `updated` column with type timestamp
- create a Kafka JDBC Source Connector config for this table having `batch.max.rows: 10` and `timestamp.column.name=updated`
- insert 11 entries in the table with the same `updated`

Connector retrieves all 11 entries correctly

- update all 11 rows with the same `updated`

Connector again retrieves all 11 entries correctly

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe the docs are wrong. If you dont want data to be ignored, in any situation, use Debezium / CDC connectors, not polling / JDBC solutions